# SharePoint 2013 OOTB DateTime Control not working with Custom Masterpage

Tags: custom-masterpage, datepicker

I Created a SharePoint 2013 custom list which has the Date Time control. On clicking of the Date control, it is not rendering properly. It works perfectly with default master pages but not with custom. Fyi.. I have my custom master page under /_catalogs and the master page has the Type="GhostableInLibrary".

[image: DatePicker]

Any help to fix this issue would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Deepa

Comment: Pls check your custom masterpage . looks like some css or html issue

Answer (score 1):

Try adding all the MasterPage properties to your Module, i.e:

```
<Module Name="MasterPageModule" List="116" Path="MasterPageModule" RootWebOnly="True" Url="_catalogs/masterpage">

    <File Path="Custom.master" Url="Custom.master" Type="GhostableInLibrary">
      <Property Name="ContentTypeId" Value="0x0101000F1C8B9E0EB4BE489F09807B2C53288F0054AD6EF48B9F7B45A142F8173F171BD100B9A7C3A99DC9734F99D34D6386BC2AAE" />
      <Property Name="FileLeafRef" Value="Custom.master" />
      <Property Name="UIVersion" Value=";#15;#" />
      <Property Name="HtmlDesignAssociated" Value="FALSE" />
      <Property Name="ContentType" Value="ASP NET Master Page" />
      <Property Name="_ModerationStatus" Value="3" />
      <Property Name="FSObjType" Value="0" />
    </File> 

  </Module>
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the response, Adding these properties did not help.

Comment: Open the Developer Tools in your browser then have a look at the console, see if any files failed to load.

Answer (score 0):

Its is CSS issue, You should be missing a CSS reference ... Use Chrome or firebug to find the CSS file that is used for the Calendar control and try including it ..

Comment: Thanks for your response, I tried referring the CSS in the master page as well, tried adding the particular CSS classes in the custom css we have for the site. Also I tried referring the CSS link in the iframe.aspx page. These changes does not fix the issue.